# GPU sensors values and behaviour under load

Tags: gpu, temperature, lm-sensors

I was checking sensors and it shows this output

```
amdgpu-pci-1c00
Adapter: PCI adapter
vddgfx:       +0.72 V  
fan1:        1017 RPM
temp1:        +28.0°C  (crit = +94.0°C, hyst = -273.1°C)
power1:       30.18 W  (cap = 170.00 W)
```

What do `crit =` and `hyst =` values mean? Why hyst is negative value?

I also noticed that my GPU temperatures increase and drop very fast, from 75' degrees Celsius to 28' in like less than a minute, is this okay? Or is this censors reading issue? 
Also, once my GPU gets hot up to 70-75 degrees Celsius, shouldn't the fan start spinning faster to cool GPU down? It spins at 1017 rpm in idle, then reaches 1300 rpm when temperature goes to 60' Celsius, and drops to 1017 rpm when temperature reaches 75-80' Celsius. Is this an issue with my GPU?